# Is it possible to extend Prometheus metrics in Substrate?

Tags: rust, prometheus, metrics

Is it possible to register custom metrics to be exported via `Prometheus`? Specifically, we would like to write values specific to the runtime - e.g. TVL, average throughput, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to register custom metrics to be exported via Prometheus. Prometheus provides a mechanism for registering custom collectors, which can be used to collect metrics from any source.

To register a custom collector, you need to create a new Rust struct that implements the `PrometheusCollector` trait. This trait defines a number of methods that are used to collect and export metrics.

Once you have created your custom collector, you can register it with Prometheus by calling the `register_collector` function. This function takes a reference to your custom collector and a name for the collector.

For example, the following code registers a custom collector that collects the TVL and average throughput of a runtime:

```rust
struct TvlValueCollector;

impl PrometheusCollector for TvlValueCollector {
    fn collect(&self) -> Vec<MetricFamily> {
        let mut metrics = Vec::new();

        let tvl = runtime.tvl();
        let throughput = runtime.average_throughput();

        metrics.push(MetricFamily::build(
            "tvl",
            "Total value locked",
            vec![Metric::build("value", tvl, "microEth")],
        ));
        metrics.push(MetricFamily::build(
            "throughput",
            "Average throughput",
            vec![Metric::build("value", throughput, "microEth/second")],
        ));

        return metrics;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let collector = TvlValueCollector;
    Prometheus::register_collector(collector, "tvl_collector");

    Prometheus::start();
}
```

This code will register a custom collector called `tvl_collector`. This collector will collect the TVL and average throughput of the runtime, and export them as Prometheus metrics.

For more information on registering custom collectors, please see the Prometheus documentation: https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/.